Как корректно перенести запрос из Access в Windows Forms C#
Всем привет, у меня не получается перенести запрос из Access в мою программу на C#
Я так понял дела в синтаксисе, можете пожалуйста помочь с переносом данного запроса
Сам запрос в  Access выглядит так
SELECT Книги.Название AS Название_книги, Sum(Товарная_накладная.[Количество экземпляров]) AS Общее_количество_экземпляров, Nz(Sum(соединительная.Количество),0) AS Сколько_раз_взяли, Nz(Sum(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга='возвращена',соединительная.Количество,0)),0) AS Сколько_раз_вернули, Nz(Sum(соединительная.Количество),0)-Nz(Sum(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга='возвращена',соединительная.Количество,0)),0) AS Задолженность, Sum(Товарная_накладная.[Количество экземпляров])-(Nz(Sum(соединительная.Количество),0)-Nz(Sum(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга='возвращена',соединительная.Количество,0)),0)) AS Остаток_экземпляров
FROM (Книги LEFT JOIN соединительная ON Книги.Код = соединительная.Код_книги) LEFT JOIN Товарная_накладная ON Книги.Код = Товарная_накладная.Код_книги
GROUP BY Книги.Название;


Но так как Nz не поддерживает Microsoft JET Database Engine, я пробовал через
SELECT 
    Книги.Название AS Название_книги, 
    SUM(Товарная_накладная.[Количество экземпляров]) AS Общее_количество_экземпляров, 
    IIf(SUM(соединительная.Количество) Is Null, 0, SUM(соединительная.Количество)) AS Сколько_раз_взяли, 
    IIf(SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0)) Is Null, 0, SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0))) AS Сколько_раз_вернули, 
    IIf(SUM(соединительная.Количество) Is Null, 0, SUM(соединительная.Количество)) - IIf(SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0)) Is Null, 0, SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0))) AS Задолженность, 
    SUM(Товарная_накладная.[Количество экземпляров]) - (IIf(SUM(соединительная.Количество) Is Null, 0, SUM(соединительная.Количество)) - IIf(SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0)) Is Null, 0, SUM(IIf(соединительная.Статус_книга = 'возвращена', соединительная.Количество, 0)))) AS Остаток_экземпляров
FROM 
    (Книги 
    LEFT JOIN соединительная ON Книги.Код = соединительная.Код_книги) 
    LEFT JOIN Товарная_накладная ON Книги.Код = Товарная_накладная.Код_книги
GROUP BY 
    Книги.Название;


Выводит ошибку:
Ошибка в списке аргументов функции: "IS" не распознан. Ошибка в списке аргументов функции: "=" не распознан. Не удается выполнить синтаксический разбор текста запроса.
Как мне все же выполнить данный запрос, можете пожалуйста подсказать
Надеюсь описал понятно, делаю это первый раз так что сильно не бейте ((

А почему вы решили что он должен поддерживать IS? Дайте ссылку на документацию, которой вы руководствовались, пока писали запрос. Почему древний JET? Почему не OLE DB? Я бы на вашем месте начал бы с чтения документации о том, а как же правильно подключить БД https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms
